# Pagination and Accepting Cookies with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, cookies, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an archive for sentiment analysis, but I can't seem to accept cookies or click the "next" button. When I try to accept cookies, the error alternates between ""element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (906, 934)" and "Message: move target out of bounds".

I am trying to scrape the publication links and date/publication information from https://www.regeringen.se/dokument-och-publikationer. The code I currently have collects everything for the first page, but the page is dynamic so simply modifying the URL isn't moving to the next page. I've tried many different strategies with Selenium, but I'm new to it and keep getting hit with the same errors.

Here is the code I've been fooling around with trying to get the pagination and accept cookies buttons to work:

```
# Base URL for the search query
url = "https://www.regeringen.se/dokument-och-publikationer"

# Set up the Selenium WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')  # You can use other web drivers like Firefox if you prefer

# Open the URL in the web browser
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the cookie accept button to be clickable and click it using XPath
try:
    cookie_accept_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'))
    )

    # Click the cookie accept button
    cookie_accept_button.click()
    print("Accepted Cookies")

    # Wait for the "Next" button to be clickable
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.filter-pagination[data-page="2"]'))
    )

    # Click the "Next" button
    next_button.click()
    print("Next Button Clicked")

    # You can perform further actions on the next page here

except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)

# Don't forget to close the WebDriver when you are done
driver.quit()
```

Here is the code that I was using before I shifted to trying to use Selenium:

```
# Cycle through first three pages of archive and grab the links that lead to useful content

# Base URL for the search query
base_url = "https://www.regeringen.se/dokument-och-publikationer/?"
query_param = "page="
page_number = 1

# List to store all extracted links
all_links = []
all_dates = []

while page_number <= 3: 
    # Construct the URL for the current page
    url = f"{base_url}{query_param}{page_number}"

    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find all <ul> tags with class "list--block list--search"
    ul_tags = soup.find_all("ul", class_="list--block cl")

    # Extract and prepend "https://www.regeringen.se/" to each link (excluding links that start with "/tx")
    links = []
    dates = []
    for ul_tag in ul_tags:
        # Find all <a> tags within the current <ul> tag
        a_tags = ul_tag.find_all("a", href=True)
        # Extract href attribute (link) from each <a> tag and prepend the base URL before appending to the links list
        for a in a_tags:
            link = a["href"]
            # Check if the link does not start with "/tx" before adding the base URL and appending it
            if not link.startswith("/tx"):
                full_url = "https://www.regeringen.se" + link
                links.append(full_url)
        # Find all <div> tags with class "block--timeLinks"
        date_links_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='block--timeLinks')
        for t in date_links_divs:
            date = t.get_text(strip=True)
            dates.append(date)

    # Add the links from the current page to the list of all links
    all_links.extend(links)
    all_dates.extend(dates)

    # Check if there is a "Next" button on the current page
    next_button = soup.find("a", class_="filter-pagination")

    # If there is no "Next" button, break the loop (reached the last page)
    if not next_button:
        break

    # Move to the next page
    page_number += 1

    # Introduce a randome delay time before the next request
    time.sleep(randint(5, 10))  # Adjust the delay time as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your selenium code as below, it will click on the `Accept Cookies` button and after that it will click on `Next` button.

```
# Set up the Selenium WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')  # You can use other web drivers like Firefox if you prefer
driver.maximize_window()

# Open the URL in the web browser
driver.get(url)

# Create WebDriverWait object
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Wait for the cookie accept button to be clickable and click it using XPath
cookie_accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn c-cookie__action js-cookie-click']")))
# Below line will use Javascript to click on the cooke accept button
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cookie_accept_button)
print("Accepted Cookies")

# Wait for the "Next" button to be clickable
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='nav--pagination__next']//a")))
next_button.click()
print("Next Button Clicked")

# Don't forget to close the WebDriver when you are done
driver.quit()
```

**Console output:**

```
Accepted Cookies
Next Button Clicked

Process finished with exit code 0
```